# Routing with optional parameters for webform is just giving page not found

Tags: 8, routes, webforms

I created my webform to accept parameters via a standard `$_GET` and this works fine but is quite unsecure I am told and should rather use clean URL's via Drupal 8 built in Routing.

As such I set up a module to support my webform and contains only a `info.yml` and `routing.ynl`. The routing is as below, I got the format from [Using parameters in routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/using-parameters-in-routes) but suspect I just haven't grasped it.

```
abc_enquire_form_routing.webform:
  path: /form/enquire/{type}/{region}/{destination}
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  defaults:
    type: 'tailor-made-holidays'
```

Normal form access is via http://abcsite.localhost/form/enquire

Form access with parameters as a get (For illustration) was: http://abcsite.localhost/form/enquire?type=tailor-made-holidays&region=asia&destination=48

Module name is: `abc_enquire_form_routing`

Trying to access the form with the module enabled with the above routing  through http://abcsite.localhost/form/enquire/tailor-made-holidays is simply giving me a p **"The requested page could not be found."** error. So I can only assume I am doing the routing wrong.

What I am trying to achieve is three optional parameters after the "http://abcsite.localhost/form/enquire" page of the url, e.g. http://abcsite.localhost/form/enquire/tailor-made-holidays/asia/49

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good example of doing this with webforms module ?

Comment: Routes can't support query string parameters.  You might need to define a route for each variant.

abc_enquire_form_routing.webform --abc_enquire_form_routing.webform.type -- 
abc_enquire_form_routing.webform.type.region

Comment: @jrockowitz - Thanks, I was trying to actually do away with Querystring params, and switch to a purely RESTful method of passing parameters within the route, but I cannot get the route working if I add parameters as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I found really weird the response from *jrockowitz*. Because what you are asking **is indeed possible**.

If someone else needs a proper response for this question, then you can easily do this:

```
abc_enquire_form_routing.webform:
  path: /form/enquire/{type?}/{region?}/{destination?}
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  defaults:
    type: 'tailor-made-holidays'
```

That way if **don't** add the last three parameters you won't receive any error at all.

And of course you can use them as you want in your controller :)

Btw, you can also remove the **defaults key** if you don't need it:

```
 abc_enquire_form_routing.webform:
  path: /form/enquire/{type?}/{region?}/{destination?}
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Remember to **clear your cache** after this implementation.